# Qt5 MySQL Driver Issues

Tags: mysql, driver, qt5

I'm trying to get my MySQL database interfacing with Qt5 but I can't seem to get the driver working. I've tried to compile it myself but always ran into different errors, then I upgraded to Qt 5.2 which comes with the drivers pre-compiled: `qsqlmysql.dll & qsqlmysqld.dll` but I still can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running Qt 5.2 on Windows 7 with 32-bit MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, forgot to `Copy libmysql.dll from %mysql%/lib to C:\Windows` D'oh!